# SELECT from single table one user per company

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

So a little bit of a amateur question.  I haven't worked too much with `MySQL`, but I need to pull a *query* from a table and I am not sure where I am going.

The table `core_user` has the following fields:

```
user_id
user_display_name
user_name
user_password
user_email
user_group
user_role
date_registered
language
timezone
region
```

I need to write a query to pull the following `Column`s:

```
user_display_name
user_name
user_password
user_email
```

Thing is there are sometimes up to 20 users that can have the same `user_display_name`.  I only want the query to return one result per `user_display_name`.  It doesn't matter who the user is but I can't have 20 people from the same company logging into my new module.

Can someone please give me a hand in writing this query.  I have read about doing an `SELF JOIN` to do this, but I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Go straight to the manual, or any beginner's tutorial. Do not pass go. Do not collect £200.

Comment: I don't find any questions noob since we all were once, and we still are in some concept or another, but what i want noob is that `n00b` style writing (:

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry, I did look through the manual, but having not worked in SQL much it all looked the same to me.  Your comment was just flippant and not particularly helpful.  I haven't been a member for long but every single question has been answered amazingly well, no matter how stupid and that is what has kept me coming back.  Your answer, well that's why people think programmers are elitist. Not very helpful!

Comment: Thanks @Zefnus.  Can't take the gamer out of a person I guess! ;)

Comment: I suppose there are lots of gamers in SO such as myself (: This is SO

Comment: Just saw what you meant now... hehehe... I shall keep that in mind for next time... Thanks!

Comment: Hey, programmers are people too.

Comment: @thegearbox are you sure the answer you accepted works as you expected `I only want the query to return one result per user_display_name` or are you getting *duplicate* display names with different values of name, email, password fields ? The answer *nes * gave seemed the only correct one

Comment: @Zefnus you are correct... I was rushing out the office and just did the check myself... seems as though the Nes answer is the right one... I have changed my vote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` **user_display_name** field as follows;

```
SELECT user_display_name, user_name, user_password, user_email
FROM core_user
GROUP BY user_display_name
```

This works great for `MySQL` listing *unique* display names as you suggested in question description:

> I only want the query to return one result per user_display_name

Comment: This won't result as OP expected and it will not run while `GROUP BY` contains only one field

Comment: @Zefnus - this is MySQL, so it *will* run - but it won't necessarily return the expected result!

Comment: @Strawberry Didn't expect it to run, thanks for correcting

Comment: @Zefnus as i remember DISTINCT works on whole row so if table contains users with same name and different passwords for example it returns two rows.

Comment: @nes I'm sorry, you'r right and this one is the *only* right answer. I tried running this on `SqlFiddle` and this works for `MySql`. Unfortunately i can't upvote or remove downvote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: My bad! Thanks @nes for this one... missed that one earlier as I had to dig a few pages down to a result for multiple users.  Seems as though this is bringing back only one user now.  Thanks Zefnus for noticing... As I said... n00b :)

Comment: @nes I tho it `Sql Server` way. I apologize, didn't think it would be that easy since it isn't in `Sql Server`

Comment: @thegearbox You'r welcome. Yes, i was confused at first as well thinking `Sql Server` way which is kinda takes much more to implement. I posted how i implemented

Comment: nes, @Strawberry so in mysql this just shows any single row (whichever mysql comes across first) for each `user_display_name`? At first glance I assumed this wouldn't work too - only use sql-server, interesting to know.

Comment: @OGHaza One would assume these rows to be unique, so in this particular instance, the result is entirely as expected, and will (for reasons I do not pretend to understand) typically perform fractionally faster than DISTINCT. However, because of the potential for 'unexpected' behaviour in more complex incarnations of this technique, I prefer not to advocate its use. Others here (passionately) disagree with me.

Comment: @Strawberry, I don't understand what you mean, [using DISTINCT would have a completely different effect](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b600a/3/0) when selecting 4 columns - I assume I'm misunderstanding your explanation. But testing on Fiddle I see it probably works as I suspected (effectively doing a LIMIT 1 with (most likely) no ORDER BY for each group to select the values for the non-grouped columns).

Comment: @Strawberry, actualy MySQL optimizes DISTINCT by turning it into GROUP BY :) [DISTINCT optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct to get only one result for all same username.
`SELECT DISTINCT user_display_name, user_name, user_password, user_email

FROM core_user`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your requirement, all you need to do is:

```
Select distinct user_display_name, user_name, user_password, user_email 
from core_user;
```

This will give all the *unique* result sets from the table.

Comment: Thanks!! Works perfectly now... I tried that one yesterday, but couldn't get it to work, must have left something out so that is why I was looking at other options! Thanks for the assist!

Comment: @the gearbox: Most welcome.  :)

Comment: seems as though the answer below is the correct one.  Didn't do a full look through the results.

Comment: Yup, OP wants only `distinct user_display_name`, not entire distinct rows (since presumably every row is distinct)

Answer (score 0):

The answer [nes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675581/select-from-single-table-one-user-per-company-n00b-i-know/21675698#21675698) gave works great for `MySql` and is correct answer to the question.

I was just curious about how to do that in `Sql Server` since *projecting* a column that is not included in *grouping* is not allowed. So i came to accept this as a good solution;

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
  id int primary key,
  name nvarchar(50), 
  email nvarchar(50), 
  number int
) 

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (1, 'name1', 'a@a.com', 1)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (2, 'name1', 'b@b.com', 2)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (3, 'name2', 'c@c.com', 5)

SELECT t1.name, t1.number, t1.email 
FROM @table1 As t1 JOIN (SELECT name, MAX(id) As maxId FROM @table1 GROUP BY name) As t2
    ON t2.maxId = t1.id
```

Alias `t2` is the result of *subquery* which returns the *distinct* names with additional column `id` information (`MAX()` is used as aggregate to guarantee there will only be one name and no duplicates, it could be `MIN()` aswell). `t2` is *joined* with `t1` on `id` fields ensuring that there will be *unique* names.

The only *constraint* is; there must be an `id` field or any other **`unique key`**

Just wanted to share, sorry if considered off-topic